# Corda - Stored data size in the Vault database reaches maximum database limit

Tags: corda

Please consider the following scenario -

A Corda network consists of three nodes - "Node A", "Node B" and "Node C", and a validating notary "Notary 1".
There are multiple transactions between "Node A" and "Node B" & "Node A" and "Node C".

Suppose, the total size of the data in the vault database of the "Node A" reaches the maximum limit of the database. In such case we would have to clear the "Node A" database for making space for future transactions. Please answer following questions related to this case -

Questions:

1. In order to make space in "Node A" database and to keep the vaults of all peers in sync, should we remove the historical consumed transactions records from the vault databases of all the peer nodes?
2. If we remove the historical consumed transactions records only from the "Node A" vault database, would it affect the future flows between "Node A" and other nodes?
3. Is there already a defined procedure in Corda to handle the above this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered here: [How Do I Purge Data From Corda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418362/how-do-i-purge-data-from-corda)

For all three of your questions, you need to make sure that future transaction will not affiliate with the data you deleted.

At the current stage, we don't have any "data deletion" functionalities on the node.